# Laravel `Auth::routes()` encapsulated within a prefix group using a parameter as prefix

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-8

I'm trying to use Laravel `Auth::routes()` encapsulated within a prefix group for localization purposes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}', 'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}']], function () {
    Auth::routes();
});
```

In my views I now create routes providing the current language like this `route('password.confirm', app()->getLocale())`

But when I try to use the "forgot password" function, an exception is thrown. I believe this is caused because Laravel internally creates a password reset link, using a named route without passing along the current language parameter.

```
Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException
Missing required parameter for [Route: password.reset] 
[URI: {locale}/password/reset/{token}] [Missing parameter: locale].
```

Is it possible to use `Auth::routes()` and inject the missing "locale" parameter globally in some way? Or what would be the suggested way to do it without rewriting Laravels authentication methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution. Thanks to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49380950/9405862 it inspired me to add a middleware to my route group which adds the missing parameter to the URLs:

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => HandleRouteLang::class,
    'prefix' => '{locale}',
    'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}']
], function () { 
    Auth::routes();
});
```

My middleware now looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\UrlGenerator;

class HandleRouteLang
{
    private $url;

    public function __construct(UrlGenerator $url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Set current language by locale parameter within URLs
        if ($request->route("locale")) {
            app()->setlocale($request->route("locale"));
        }

        // Set default language value for routes created by named routes
        $this->url->defaults([
            'locale' => app()->getLocale(),
        ]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```